# Screen, process kill on disconnect?

Tags: linux, terminal

Am hoping this can be cleared up :

Given, screen session running, and open (attached) in a terminal.

Question.

If the terminal session is terminated, without being detached from the screen session, would the active process running in the screen session be killed/halted/stopped etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in the [manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Detach), found by looking for `SIGHUP`:

> Command: autodetach state (none)
>
> Sets whether screen will automatically detach upon hangup, which saves all your running programs until they are resumed with a screen -r command. When turned off, a hangup signal will terminate screen and all the processes it contains. Autodetach is on by default.